# Getting plotly.graph_objs attribute error for FigureWidget

Tags: python, plotly, attributeerror

I get the following error in Jupyter Notebook:

```
AttributeError: module 'plotly.graph_objs' has no attribute 'FigureWidget'
```

I have verified that Plotly package is installed as is ipywidgets, Flask and Dash.

```py
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import figure_factory as FF
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

Not sure what I need to install or update to get this to work.

Comment: Related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1630

Comment: I saw that posting and I confirmed ipywidget has been installed.

Answer (score 1):

For me even when plotly was upgraded ipywidget wasn't.
executing `pip3 install ipywidgets --upgrade`

make sure you enable these extensions on this notebook:
`jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension --sys-prefix`
`jupyter nbextension enable --py plotlywidget --sys-prefix`